# How do I extract the following data from an Excel data collection?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below is a small example database that I have created for reference.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qODH.png]

What function can I use to only display users that have 0 '`Data Used`', '`Minutes Used`' and all '`Amount Used`' rows must be no more than 1 for that user?

In this particular example, only the information for '`Steven Jones`' would be displayed.

Comment: This question lacks details about effort you've put into this so far. What have you tried? Have you tried using a pivot table?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a helper column onto the end of your results and filter on that to show/hide as you need.

This function works by counting how many rows fail your criteria - ie how many rows have either more than 0 Data or Minutes Used, or more than 1 amount used.

If any rows fail any of your criteria then the `if()` statement returns "hide". If there are no matching rows at all, then it's ok to include them in your results so the `if()` returns "include".

```
 =IF(
     COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$14,A2
             ,$E$2:$E$14,">0"
             ,$F$2:$F$14,">0"
             ,$G$2:$G$14,">1"
             )>0
    ,"Hide"
    ,"Include"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there's an error here. A complete row must have values other than 0 & 1 respectively to hide the particular user.

Comment: The logic applied here follows the criteria laid out in your question: `"only display users that have 0 'Data Used', 'Minutes Used' and all 'Amount Used' rows must be no more than 1 **for that user?** In this particular example, only the information for 'Steven Jones' would be displayed."`

Comment: If I've misunderstood the criteria please edit your question to make it very clear what the requirements are.

Comment: This exactly solves the asked question and provides the same result as the example. You should tell where this behaves not like you want it to ?